# how to redirect loggedin in users from viewing login page in django, using generic views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

i want to prevent/redirect logged in users from viewing login or signup pages, i did that through views like this

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #redirect
    else:
        #view form`
```

but now i switch to generic view

```
class LoginView(generic.edit.FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "people/user_login_form.html"
    success_url = '/'
```

and couldn't use the variable 'request', after some searching i found a suggestion to use a custom_login function but i didn't know how to complete it

```
def custom_login(request, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        #what should i implement here to render LoginView.as_view() ?
```

is there a better way ? permissions maybe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would override `dispatch` method:

```
class LoginView(generic.edit.FormView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpRedirect('/whatever/')
        else:
            return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```